# jQuery - Finding the row number of the current select element within its change handler

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table. In this table have select element. How can I find in which table row is select element, from within the select's event handler:

```
$('#selectElemID').live('change', function(){...});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

EDIT (two years later): Please don't do it the way I previously described, it is a total waste as table rows already have a `rowIndex` property, so there's just no need to compute anything:

```
$('#selectElemID').live("change", function (){
    alert($(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex);
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7g7g/)

`<silliness>`

This should do it, if you want the row number of the current select element (which is what I understand from the question):

```
$('#selectElemID').live('change', function(){
    alert($(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length + 1);
});
```

To explain:

```
$(this).closest("tr")
```

means select the closest parent `tr` of this select element.

```
.prevAll("tr").length + 1
```

means select all the *previous* rows, and get me the length of the returned collection. Increment it by one to get the current row number, because we are at **total previous rows + 1**.

For more information:

- http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/
- http://api.jquery.com/closest/

`</silliness>`

Comment: it's nice to see the additional explanation with answers and not just code to solve the issue.

Comment: @karim79 Thanks buddy it helped me also!!

Answer (score 2):

also:

```
$('#selectElemID').live('change', function(){
    alert($(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex);
});
```